# Access Ubuntu VM from Ubuntu host

Tags: server, apache2

I installed Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.10 LTS on a VM itself installed on Ubuntu 12.10 LTS.
After I set what I needed, I can access **from my host machine** to my server to test the website I am developing this way:

```
 http://11.10.10.2/mywebsite/index.php
```

My Question: is there a way to substitue the address 11.10.10.2 with a name of my choice ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

type as

```
nano /etc/hosts
```

and in that file made the entry as

```
11.10.10.2 mywebsite.com
```

Then you can access your webiste with

```
mywebsite.com/mywebsite/index.php
```

Comment: Sorry, for my other question: it works exactly as you told me ONLY inside the VM, but I would love to use the same address (mywebsite.com/mywebsite/index.php) from my host machine but I can not: it works only if I write 11.10.10.2

Comment: From my host machine, this works : http://11.10.10.2/mywebsite/index.php<br><br> But mywebsite.com/mywebsite/index.php works only inside the VM

Comment: you have to add this in your host machine and have you switched on firewalls in your VM ?

Comment: Which Virtual Machine are you using. According to Virtual-Box you can change your Virtual-Box Machine Network Settings `NAT` Change it to `Internal Network` Then you can change according to you. Also add in your `sudo vim /etc/hosts' file to add your address. Like Above answer.